# How can I define an AngularJS factory using TypeScript class that has constructor parameters

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I want to write a TypeScript class that gets a "prefix" parameter in the constructor, this class also needs access to a LogService inject.

Using plain JavaScript you should do it like this:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).factory('LogWithPrefixFactory', ['LogService', function(LogService) {
    var LogWithPrefixFactory = function(prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    LogWithPrefixFactory.prototype.log = function(txt) {
        // we have access to the injected LogService
        LogService.log(this.prefix, txt);
    }

    return LogWithPrefixFactory;
}]);
```

So when you inject this factory to a controller, you can initiate it many times like this (No need to inject the LogService):

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('Ctrl', function(LogWithPrefixFactory) {
    var foo = new LogWithPrefixFactory("My PREFIX");
    var foo = new LogWithPrefixFactory("My OTHER PREFIX");
}
```

How would you define this Factory in a TypeScript class?
TypeScript classes can not be defined inside functions...
This class should have access to the LogService, but it can't get it in one of the injects.

Comment: Related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620275

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are at least 2 options.

First option, have `LogWithPrefixFactory` provide a method `getInstance` that returns the prefixed logger.

```
module services {
  class LogService {
    $window: any;

    constructor($window: any) {
      this.$window = $window;
    }

    log(prefix: string, txt: string) {
      this.$window.alert(prefix + ' :: ' + txt);
    }
  }
  angular.module('services').service('LogService', ['$window', LogService]);


  export interface ILog {
    log: (txt) => void;
  }

  export class LogWithPrefixFactory {
    logService: LogService;

    constructor(logService: LogService) {
      this.logService = logService;
    }

    getInstance(prefix: string): ILog {
      return {
        log: (txt: string) => this.logService.log(prefix, txt);
      }
    }
  }

  angular.module('services').service('LogWithPrefixFactory', ['LogService', services.LogWithPrefixFactory]);
}
```

Which can be used in the controller like:

```
this.log1 = logWithPrefixFactory.getInstance("prefix1");
this.log2 = logWithPrefixFactory.getInstance("prefix2");
```

Complete plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tahSo5uouPAcemjmXOEv?p=preview).

Second option (similar to another answer), give Angular another function to be used as a constructor, which handles manually the `LogService` constructor injection (personally, I don't like `static`).

```
angular.module('services').service('LogWithPrefixFactory', ['LogService', function(logService) {
    return function LogWithPrefixFactory(prefix) {
      return new LogWithPrefix(prefix, logService);
    };
}]);
```

Which can be used in the controller like:

```
this.log1 = new LogWithPrefixFactory("prefix1");
this.log2 = new LogWithPrefixFactory("prefix2");
```

or even:

```
this.log1 = LogWithPrefixFactory("prefix1");
this.log2 = LogWithPrefixFactory("prefix2");
```

`LogWithPrefixFactory` is injected in the controller but it's not the TypeScript class constructor, it's the intermediate function which returns the actual instance of the class, after it has been "manually" injected with `LogService`.

Complete plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/O2hn5Vy3UQCA7KqRZZIq?p=preview).

Note: These plunkers synchronously compile typescript on the browser. I have tested it only on Chrome. No guarantees that they'll work. Finally, I manually added a small part of  angular.d.ts. Full file was very big and my proxy does not allow large POSTs.

Comment: Yea, wrapping it with another function that get only the needed parameters is what I needed.

Comment: Why are these services and not factories?

Answer (score 23):

The following is one way to achieve this:

```
class LogWithPrefixFactory {
    static LogService;
    constructor(prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    log = function(txt) {
        // we have access to the injected LogService
        LogService.log(this.prefix, txt);
    }
}

angular.module('myModule', []).factory('LogWithPrefixFactory', ['LogService', function(LogService) {
    LogWithPrefixFactory.LogService = LogService;
    return LogWithPrefixFactory;
}]);


angular.module('myModule').controller('Ctrl', function(LogWithPrefixFactory) {
    var foo = new LogWithPrefixFactory("My PREFIX");
    var foo = new LogWithPrefixFactory("My OTHER PREFIX");
});
```

**Rational:** You effectively want a static property in a the LogWithPrefixFactory (using a closure in JS) , *and* you want it to come from Angular.

Comment: This is a great solution! but Kos gave a better way. because his solution was to keep the class looking the same as a regular class with injects, and not consts.

Comment: there are not constants here. Only static. Static just means that all instances of the class share the same non-instance reference (effectively identical to how a service works). The only difference here is that instead of a static injector returning static services shared by all instances, this has a static service without the injector.

Comment: I think this answer is better because it is a factory like you asked for.

Answer (score 8):

I have achieved like below

```
module Dashboard {
    export class LayoutServiceFactory {
        static $inject = ["$q", "$http"];
        private q: ng.IQService;
        private http: ng.IHttpService;

        constructor(private $q: ng.IQService, private $http: ng.IHttpService) {
            this.q = $q;
            this.http = $http;
        }

        getDataFromServer(serviceUrl) {
            var deferred = this.q.defer();
            this.http.get(serviceUrl, null)
                .then(response => {

                    deferred.resolve((response) as any);

                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        static factory() {
            var instance = ($q: ng.IQService, $http: ng.IHttpService) =>
                new LayoutServiceFactory($q, $http);
            return instance;
        }
    }

    appModule.factory("LayoutService", LayoutServiceFactory.factory());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
    namespace Services
    {
      export class MyService
      {
        constructor( protected $someService :any )
        {
          return this;
        }
      }
    }
    angular.module( 'myModule', [] ).factory( Services );
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how  i do it

```
 namespace app {
             let app =angular.module('foo',[]);
               app.factory(factories);//for registering whatever is there in factories namespace

      }

 namespace app.factories {


 export class fooFactory {

    static $inject = ['fooHelperService']
    constructor(fooHelperService: services.fooHelperService) {

        return {

            fooFunc: () => {

               return 'hellow world'
            }
        }
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: I get: 
Return type of constructor signature must be assignable to the instance type of the class. Type fooFunc:() => string is not assignable to type 'fooFactory'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and fooFunc does not exist in type fooFactory

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type that allows you to define what the constructor of the factory looks like:

```ts
// Defining the factory

// THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART!!
export type SelectorFactory = new (config: any) => Selector;

export class Selector {

    constructor(protected config: any, protected $http: ng.IHttpService) {
        // do some stuff
    }
}

angular.module('app')
    .factory('Selector', ($http: ng.IHttpService) => {
        // This is what the factory looks like to the end user
        return (config: any) => {
            return new Selector(config, $http);
        };
    });

// Using the factory
export class SampleCtrl {
    constructor(public SelectorFactory: SelectorFactory) {
        let config = { op: 1 };

        let selector: Selector = new SelectorFactory(config);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error with this is: "error TS4081: Exported type alias 'SelectorFactory' has or is using private name 'Selector'

Comment: try changing `class Selector` to  `export class Selector` maybe?