# Can I create a TypeScript class within a function and refer to its parameters?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

E.g. in angularJS I may use the following construction:

```javascript
myApp.factory('MyFactory', function(injectable) {
    return function(param) {
        this.saySomething = function() {
            alert("Param=" + param + " injectable=" +injectable);
        }
    };
});
```

This can later be used like this:

```javascript
function(MyFactory) {
    new MyFactory().saySomething();
}
```

When the function passed to the method `factory` gets invoked, the param `injectable` is caged and will further be available to new instances of `MyFactory` without any need to specify that parameter again.

Now I want to use TypeScript and obviously  I want to specify that my `MyFactory` is newable, and has a function `saySomething`. How could I do this elegantly?

I could write something like this:

```
class MyFactory {
    constructor(private injectable, private param) {}
    saySomething() {
        alert(...);
    }
}
myApp.factory('myFactory', function(injectable) {
    return function(param) {
        return new MyFactory(injectable, param);
    }
});
```

But this changes the API:

```
function(myFactory) {
    myFactory().saySomething();
}
```

I wonder if it could be more elegant, because I like how the "new" expresses quite clearly that a new unique object is created and this object creation is the whole purpose of the factory.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056458
This question could have been named "TypeScript and AngularJS dependency injection without polluting the constructor?"

Answer (score 1):

** Edit: TypeScript >= 1.6 supports [class expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/497) and you can now write things like:

```
myApp.factory(injectable: SomeService) {
  class TodoItem {
    ...
  }
}
```

** Original answer:

I have the same problem: with AngularJS and ES5, I enjoy dependency injection not polluting constructors and be able to use the `new` keyword.

With ES6 you can wrap a class inside a function, this is not yet supported by TypeScript (see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/307).

Here what I do (MyFactory is now class TodoItem from a todo app to be more relevant):

```
class TodoItem {
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
  date: Date;

  constructor(private injectable: SomeService) { }

  doSomething() {
    alert(this.injectable);
  }
}

class TodoItemFactory() {
  constructor(private injectable: SomeService) { }

  create(): TodoItem {
    return new TodoItem(this.injectable);
  }

  // JSON from the server
  createFromJson(data: any): TodoItem {
    var todoItem = new TodoItem(this.injectable);
    todoItem.title = data.title;
    todoItem.completed = data.completed;
    todoItem.date = data.date;
    return todoItem;
  }
}

// In ES5: myApp.factory('TodoItem', function(injectable) { ... });
myApp.service('TodoItemFactory', TodoItemFactory);


class TodosCtrl {
  // In ES5: myApp.controller('TodosCtrl', function(TodoItem) { ... });
  constructor(private todoItemFactory: TodoItemFactory) { }

  doSomething() {
    // In ES5: var todoItem1 = new TodoItem();
    var todoItem1 = this.todoItemFactory.create();

    // In ES5: var todoItem2 = TodoItem.createFromJson(...)
    var todoItem2 = this.todoItemFactory.createFromJson(
      {title: "Meet with Alex", completed: false}
    );
  }
}
```

This is less elegant than with ES5 and functions (and not using classes with TypeScript is a no go) :-/

What I would like to write instead:

```
@Factory
@InjectServices(injectable: SomeService, ...)
class TodoItem {
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
  date: Date;

  // No DI pollution
  constructor() { }

  saySomething() {
    alert(this.injectable);
  }

  static createFromJson(data: string): TodoItem {
    ...
  }
}

@Controller
@InjectFactories(TodoItem: TodoItem, ...)
class TodosCtrl {
  constructor() { }

  doSomething() {
    var todoItem1 = new TodoItem();

    var todoItem2 = TodoItem.createFromJson({title: "Meet with Alex"});
  }
}
```

Or with functions:

```
myApp.factory(injectable: SomeService) {
  class TodoItem {
    title: string;
    completed: boolean;
    date: Date;

    // No constructor pollution
    constructor() { }

    saySomething() {
      alert(injectable);
    }

    static createFromJson(data: string): TodoItem {
      ...
    }
  }
}

myApp.controller(TodoItem: TodoItem) {
  class TodosCtrl {
    constructor() { }

    doSomething() {
      var todoItem1 = new TodoItem();

      var todoItem2 = TodoItem.createFromJson({title: "Meet with Alex"});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As of TypeScript 1.6, class expressions are supported.

Answer (score 0):

> I could write something like this

This is what I do

> Can I create a TypeScript class within a function

No it needs to be at the top level of the file or in a module. Just FYI if were able to create it inside a function the information would be locked inside that function and at least the *type* info would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason for instantiating multiple instances of MyFactory? Would you not want a single instance of your factory to be injected into your dependent code?

I think using the class declaration you provided will actually look like this once injected:

```
function(myFactory) {
    myFactory.saySomething();
}
```

If you are really needing to pass a constructor function into your dependent code, then I think you will have to ditch TypeScript classes, since they can't be defined inside of a function which means you would have no way to create a closure on a variable injected into such function.

You do always have the option of just using a function in TypeScript instead of a class. Still get the strong typing benefits and can call 'new' on it since it is still a .js function at the end of the day. Here's a slightly more TypeScriptiffied version:

```
myApp.factory('MyFactory', (injectable: ng.SomeService) => {

    return (param: string) => {

        return {
            saySomething: () {
                alert("Param=" + param + " injectable=" +injectable);
            }
        };
    };
});
```