# Using angular factory in separate typescript file

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I define a factory in one file (Movie.ts), like this:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('moviesServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Movie', Movie);

Movie.$inject = ['$resource'];

function Movie($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/movies/:id');
}
})();
```

Then I try to use it in another file (MoviesController.ts), note that it is TypeScript:

```
function MoviesAddController($scope, $location, Movie) {
    $scope.movie = new Movie();
    $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.movie.$save(function () {
            $location.path('/');
        });
    };
}
```

TypeScript now complains on "new Movie();" with the error message "Cannot resolve symbol 'Movie'."

*How can I define that Movie is a factory?* I tried exporting Movie as a class but I don't know how to convert the factory to a TypeScript class.

This works in JavaScript and the example is taken from [this tutorial](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/01/16/asp-net-5-and-angularjs-part-3-adding-client-routing).

Comment: should look into this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24058604/2435473

Comment: I don't mean to criticize but there isn't a lick of TS in those examples. You might be better off following that tutorial with just JS and then once you have a grasp of how angular works come back and start writing it in TS. Also pankajparkar link is good but the more TS way of handling this is actually the answer @basarat  gave to that question.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I am rewriting the tutorial in TypeScript to get a better understanding of TypeScript. The above snippets are 100% JavaScript and ripped straight from the tutorial. I have rewritten them in my TS files (proably poorly though). Can you give an example of how the two snippets could be converted to TypeScript, preferably using classes?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm still learning TypeScript and I don't know if it helps anyone but I solved the above problem by first rewriting the factory to a service, as such:

```
export class WebApiService
{
    static $inject = ["$resource"];
    constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService)
    {
    }

    public movies()
    {
        return this.$resource("/api/movies/:id");
    }
}
app.service("webApiService", WebApiService);
```

Then, in the controller, I used this code:

```
var Movie = webApiService.movies();
$scope.movie = new Movie();
```

A simplified example of using $resource to create a new entity would be:

```
var Movie = $resource("/api/movies/:id");
$scope.movie = new Movie();
```